# How to set an image source from string array in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I just need to know how to set its source on the `newImage.source = "asset/%myArray%";` line from the array above it. I'm sure there is an easy solution. I'm just not sure how to word the question on Google...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete = "init()">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        //Gabe Dougherty
        //n221
        //9-27-12

        import mx.controls.Image;

        //array of movies
        public var myArray:Array = ["batman.jpg","cabin.jpg","christmasVaction.jpg","inception,jpg"];

        //init function
        public function init():void{

            //loops 4 times
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

                var arrayEntry:String = myArray[i];

                //makes new image
                var newImage:Image = new Image();

                //sets the image source for each image
                newImage.source = "asset/%myArray%";

                //adds the image to the stage
                grpMovies.addElement(newImage);
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:HGroup id="grpMovies" x="430" y="61" width="200" height="200">
</s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: You should accept answers if they help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your images live in `asset/` try this:

```
newImage.source = "asset/" + arrayEntry;
```

Comment: Yep that worked, I knew it was something like that but I just couldn't remember the syntax and couldn't think of what to type into google. Thanks!

Comment: @GabeDougherty if you found this answer solved your problem please mark it correct by clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Modify code in your for loop to this:

```
newImage.source = "asset\\" + myArray[i];
```

When working with `Strings` that contain paths you better use `\\` signs.